# Android screen orientation from settings

Tags: android

There is an application with the settings. 
In the settings there is an item " Screen orientation " with possible values of "Portrait ", " Landscape" , "Automatic" .
As can be seen from all the settings application must be either portrait or landscape .
Currently this is done using setRequestedOrientation () Activity in each onStart ().
Everything works , but there was a delay in the opening of the activity ( the phone in portrait position , and doing it in setRequestedOrientation landscape) .
And there is no delay if the same position number with the orientation in which we try to turn ) .

As I understand the problem is that at first activity launches with orientation sensor , 
and then recreated by software method setRequestedOrientation(). 
How to avoid delays ? Can I create activity immediately with parameter orientation? or is there an alternative ?

Tried a lot of things , including make setRequestedOrientation() in onCreate first line.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, but as far as I understand it, you want to display each of your activities in landscape mode, no matter how the device is actually held at the moment. This is working at the moment, but with a slight delay during which the current orientation of the device is messured. Your question is, how to get rid of the delay, right?